# Internationalised URLs with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to add selected *language code* to the URL instead of storing it in a *session* or *cookie*.

My first time example below sets language manually but I want to make it dynamic based on user selection. How can I produce links below?

I know that Codeigniter URLs works as `base_url/class_name/function_name/parametters`

**Note:** *My base URL is : `http://localhost/internationalisation/`*

```
http://localhost/internationalisation/en/
http://localhost/internationalisation/en/welcome
http://localhost/internationalisation/en/products/1
http://localhost/internationalisation/en/products/2
http://localhost/internationalisation/en/aboutus
http://localhost/internationalisation/en/contactus
OR spanish version
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->helper('url');

        //$this->lang->load('en', 'english');
        $this->lang->load('es', 'spanish');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}

/* EoF */
```

**VIEW**

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('en'); ?>">English</a>
<br />
<a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>es">Spanish</a>

<br /><br /><br /><br />

<h1><?php echo $this->lang->line('welcome'); ?></h1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should search the [Wiki](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/) for this kind of things for example this library [URI Language Identifier](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/URI-Language-Identifier) does what you want.